# How to implement condition for java installation

Tags: batch-file

I have to check whether java is installed or not ?
If java is installed then i have to skip it and if  not then to install it in silent mode.

I know how to install java in silent mode

```
**cls
C:\TEMP>jdk-7u4-windows-x64.exe /quiet
echo installation complete
pause**
```

but how to define condition above in batch file though i'm very new to scripting.
  Any link or reference will also work.

Answer (score 1):

This works in Windows 8 to launch the installer:

```
@echo off
java >nul 2>nul & if errorlevel 9009 jdk-7u4-windows-x64.exe /quiet
```

Comment: ++1 this is nice, I never heard!

Answer (score 0):

```
REM get the current installed Java version
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('java -version 2^>^&1 ^| find /i "version"') do SET "JAVA_current=%%~a"
IF NOT DEFINED JAVA_current (ECHO Java NOT installed.) ELSE ECHO Java version %JAVA_current% installed.
```

Comment: Thank for replying but i can't see java installing script into this code . Its simple seems to be getting version of the java.
What i need is that if java is not found in the system then it should install the java in silent mode.

Any help will be highly appreciated. thanx

Comment: If you are not able to modify my code example for your needs, you should put your question to another forum (eg. yahoo, 4chan). This is not a coding service.

Comment: Ya right. I'm sorry. But i'm new to scripting so i decided to post here. I thought i would get better approach here.
WHAT I tried now :-

REM get the current installed Java version
PAUSE
for /f "tokens=3" %%a in ('java -version 2^>^&1 ^| find /i "version"')
PAUSE
do SET "JAVA_current=%%~a"
IF NOT DEFINED JAVA_current (ECHO Java NOT installed.) 
jdk-7u4-windows-x64.exe /quiet
echo installation complete
pause
ELSE ECHO Java version %JAVA_current% installed.

But cmd propmt gets invisible after the 1st PAUSE statement means "for" condition is not working out .